# tcpdump, odd packet records

Tags: networking, traffic, tcpdump

I was checking out tcpdump and this is what i found.

```
14:27:13.244527  [|ip]
```

It is a record that as you can see contains no information except a time stamp and those brackets with |ip. while a normal packet is shown like this

```
14:27:13.244545 IP hostname.35526 > 146-66-155-52.valve.net.27021: UDP, length 132
```

have you ever noticed anything like this before? I am not sure what this packet was in or out, if it was sent from my machine or came from net.

entire timestamp history of these weirdos

```
 14:07:17.562649 [|ip]
 14:12:16.477142 [|ip]
 14:17:15.387961 [|ip] 
 14:22:14.301134 [|ip] 
 14:27:13.244527 [|ip]
 14:32:12.121007 [|ip]
 14:37:11.029139 [|ip]
```

Packets that come before and after these events seem normal or I just dont see a pattern in them. If you have encountered something similar and if you know what it could be, please, post it here.

Comment: Any details on how you came to this point please add ?

Comment: nothing specific, i just used a command tcpdump -i interface > file and used internet normally. and then looked what was inside

Answer (score 0):

I believe this indicates the IP frame was truncated (i.e. it's length is less than the length embedded in the frame). Maybe just a standalone IP fragment.